# Bubble, Sorting, Strategy

Tags: php, bubble-sort

I am studying about bubble sorting strategy at php you can see the code [Here](http://pastebin.com/rgGGWHg0),
At the main loop, there is two condition need to be true so the loop will run,
I understand that the variable is becouse we dont want our loop to run until its maximum iteration even the array is already sorted, but i did not understand why we need to check to see if we have got into the maximum iteration? why cant we just check the variable(My assumption is that we can have **some** problem at the variable and we dont want an eternal loop). any way i am not sure, i will be very thankful if some one can please tell me why we dont need to check only the variable at the the main loop, thank you all and have a nice day.

```
function sort(array &$vec)
    {
        $sorted = false;
        $size = sizeof($vec);
        for($i=0; $i<=$size-2 && !$sorted; $i++)
        {
            $maybeSorted = true;
            $from = 0;
            $till = $size-1-$i;
            for($j=$from; $j<$till; $j++)
            {
                if($vec[$j]>$vec[$j+1])
                {
                    $maybeSorted = false;
                    $temp = $vec[$j];
                    $vec[$j] = $vec[$j+1];
                    $vec[$j+1] = $temp;
                }
            }
            if($maybeSorted)
            {
                $sorted = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), there you can find the algorithem in pseudocode. Try to understand each step and start a new implemenation of it in your prefered laguage. This is the best way to learn sth. new!

Bubble sort does something like swap elements in each round and repeat this until there was nothing swapped in the last round.

**UPDATE** Some example for a good bubble sort algorithem:

```
function sort(array &$vec) {
  $n = sizeof($vec);

  do {
    $newn = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < ($n - 1); $i++) {
      if ($vec[$i] > $vec[$i + 1]) {
        $tmp         = $vec[$i];
        $vec[$i]     = $vec[$i + 1];
        $vec[$i + 1] = $tmp;
        $newn        = $i + 1;
      }
    }
    $n = $newn;
  } while ($n > 1);
}
```

1. Get the number of elements in the array (we expect that nothing is sorted right now)
2. Loop while there are elements `$n` that are not sorted so `$n > 1`
3. In the `for` loop we go through the elements and check if they need to be swapped
4. We do this till there is no element to swap so `$n` is not `> 1`

Example:

```
| 55 |  7 | 78 | 12 | 42 | 1. run
|  7 | 55 | 78 | 12 | 42 |
|  7 | 55 | 12 | 78 | 42 |
|  7 | 55 | 12 | 42 | 78 | last comparison
|  7 | 55 | 12 | 42 | 78 | 2. run
|  7 | 12 | 55 | 42 | 78 |
|  7 | 12 | 42 | 55 | 78 | last comparison (we now 78 is sorted!)
|  7 | 12 | 42 | 55 | 78 | 3. run
|  7 | 12 | 42 | 55 | 78 | sorted! (nothing was swapped)
```

(untested but should work) I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am deep inside php, i have studying it for long time studies OOP at PHP, can you please just tall me why i dont need only to check the $stored variable...

Comment: You could also reimplement this code in php ;) Only to learn the functionality of the algorithem.
The only thing you need to check is if there was nothing to swap in the last round, because when you have the maximum of runs reached, this will also be true. If you check both, you will always have the maximum number of runs.

Comment: Mabye i didnt understand you, here is what i know: i have to conditions 1 is the max loops , the other condition is the variable, i know that there variable is to check if we got the final array before we get to the final loop, but i didnt understand why we need both to be true the max loops and the variable, if you can please help me understand why do we need the max loops to be true.

Comment: You dont need this (only in your code, but this is not very good) the only thing you need to now is if there was a swap in the last run or not. If there was a swap let the loop continue, if not exit the loop and the algorithem is done. (Thats why I postet the link with an better bubble sort algorithem)

Comment: When you saying the last run you mean the inside loop or the main loop?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I added an example of how the algorithem should look like in PHP.